# applying random distribution in each row of data frame

Tags: pandas, for-loop, random, scipy, poisson

I have the following dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy as sc
import scipy.stats as sct    
d= {'col1': [1, 2,5,0.6], 'col2': [3, 4,1,0.8]}
df = pd. DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to add two new column in that dataframe but the element of two new columns are the random poisson distribution of **col1** and **col2**
I used the following coding to generate the new columns (**col3 and col4**).

```
df ['col3']  = int(sct.poisson.rvs(df.col1,size=1))
df ['col4']  = int(sct.poisson.rvs(df.col2,size=1))
```

This is the closet example of my dataframe which is quite huge and it contains 3,800,000 rows.
I can generate it using for loop. it took me too long time.

How can generate random poisson distribution based on dataframe without using loop?
Thanks

Zep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just using:

```
df['col3'] = sct.poisson.rvs(df.col1)
df['col4'] = sct.poisson.rvs(df.col2)
```

Comment: Hi Leo,
thanks for the reply and it works for this example.
When I applied it to my program, it showed be the following error:

"Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'"

Comment: @Zephyr you are welcome. If this answered your question, I would appreciate it if you kindly accepted the answer.